# Json_Encode not returning html even i try to encode JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to return HTML from PHP. I found a solution from StackOverflow which is insert `JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG` after array in `json_encode` but it does not work for me. If I simply echo it right away it's working and displays the text on page but it doesn't work with `json_encode`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mcblog";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "select ID,post_parent,post_title,post_content,post_date from wp_posts where post_content<>'' and post_title<>'' order by post_date desc limit 0,10";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data=array();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
    $html=strip_tags($row["post_content"]);
    $snippetData=array('status'=>'1','data'=>$row["post_content"]);
    echo json_encode($snippetData, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. `json_encode` is supposed to return JSON string not HTML. Is `json_encode` not returning anything? Check for errors with [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

Comment: If you want to return HTML, why are you using `json_encode`? Do you even know what you want?

Comment: actually their is html in the database and i want to remove those tags and return in json format. but problem is when i fetch from database if wirte 
echo $snippetData. it's work and display but it's now working with json_encode. but if i copy the field and assign it to variable it's also work like 
$html="<html></title></title><body></body></html>";
if i copied field from database and stored it in variable then i write json_encode(array("data"=>$html)); then it's work don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to achieve HTML without tags and return that result in JSON format. So I done it with this:

```
echo json_encode(array("id"=>"1","data" => utf8_encode(strip_tags($row["post_content"]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Exp:

```
$jsonData = json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );


JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES  = Allows you to use "//" characters.
JSON_PRETTY_PRINT = Writes the json data legibly.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).